# Problem getting MotherBoard serial number using WMI and C++added

Tags: c++, windows, com, wmi

I'm trying to get the motherboard serial number using WMI and c++.

Running WMI Tester (wbemtest.exe) and the recomended powershell function I can get the currect value, but doing it through C++ is not

The c++ code follows:

```
  HRESULT hres;
  //COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED requires that only this thread makes calls to methods os objects created by it.
  hres = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

  if (FAILED(hres)) {
  }

  hres = CoInitializeSecurity(nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr,
                              RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr,
                              EOAC_NONE, nullptr);
  if (FAILED(hres)) {
    //TODO Handle error
    CoUninitialize();
  }


  IWbemLocator *pLoc = nullptr;
  hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

  if (FAILED(hres)) {
    //TODO Handle error
    CoUninitialize();
  }

  IWbemServices *pSvc = nullptr;
  hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
                             0, 0, nullptr, &pSvc);

  if (FAILED(hres)) {
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
  }


  hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, nullptr,
                           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, EOAC_NONE);

  if (FAILED(hres)) {
    //TODO Handle error
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
  }
  IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnumerator = nullptr;

  hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard"),
                         WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, nullptr, &pEnumerator);

  if (FAILED(hres)) {
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
  }

  IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = nullptr;
  ULONG uReturn = 0;

  while (pEnumerator) {
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
    if (uReturn == 0) {
      break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "*****DeviceId*****" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Serial Number : " << vtProp.bstrVal << std::endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    pclsObj->Release();
  }

  std::cout << "***********************" << std::endl;
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  pEnumerator->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
```

The result is the wrong number and the value changes everytime I run the programm.

I'm using visual studio 2017 and it also tells me that #define _WIN32_DCOM
is never used which is unusual (I took it from the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi)

Comment: Are you sure there's no errors in any of your calls? The error handling in the code you show doesn't log or print any information, and it just let the code continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: Besides, `vtProp.bstrVal` is a `BSTR` and from what I can see `BSTR` is a wide-character pointer type. And you can't use the narrow-character `std::cout` to print wide-character strings. Either convert `vtProp.bstrVal` to a narrow-character string or use `std::wcout`.

Comment: Yes that was it, the error handling isn't finished. Now I just need to convert BSTR to string thanks a lot!